# customizing Actionbar compact item selector

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-actionbar-compat

I know there are many questions with this title , but my problem did not solved yet.

I used ActionBar Compact for implementing actionbar.

Now , i want to change its selector (item highlight) color.

I used this code for selector:

```
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/MyColor_Transparent" />

<!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/myforebackground_green" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/myforebackground_green" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mybackground_b" />
<item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mybackground_b" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/mybackground_b" />
<item android:drawable="@color/MyColor_Transparent" />
```

And also used:

```
<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/my_selector</item>
```

In styles.xml

But it didn't work.

I used this links too:

[selectable item background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970350/androidattr-selectableitembackground)

[how can i change the touch affect color of actions with actionbarsherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507587/how-can-i-change-the-touch-affect-color-of-actions-with-actionbarsherlock)

[actionbarcompat support library android selectable item background not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022778/actionbarcompat-support-library-androidselectableitembackground-not-working)

But it still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ActionBar Theme generator at http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ to make exactly what you want. Super simple, turns out great; just extract the files to your project and set the theme in the manifest (or programatically if that's your thing). And I combined it with http://android-holo-colors.com/ to make my whole app follow a common theme, but you will need to move some stuff around in the XML to get the two themes displayed as one.